# Incorrect TMX map position after moving from Andengine GLES2 to Anchor Center branch

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I'm trying to move from Andengine GLES2 to Anchor Center branch and right now have a problem with positioning of my TMX map.

My map must start in the left upper corner of screen and can scroll from this position to the right and bottom directions.

Right now after

scene.attachChild(this.mTMXTiledMap);

my map centered by left bottom corner of the screen that is good in terms of Andengine Anchor Center..
I can call this.mTMXTiledMap.setOffsetCenter(0, 0) but in this case my map will be placed into the left bottom corner.

How to place my map into the left upper corner as it was in GLES 2 branch ?

Answer (score 2):

```
this.mTMXTiledMap.setOffsetCenter(0, 1);
```

and

```
newY = scene_height - oldY;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly, this.mTMXTiledMap.setAnchorCenter(0,1) doesn't work.

Following combination works fine:

this.mTMXTiledMap.setOffsetCenter(0, 0); 
this.camera.offsetCenter(0, this.mTMXTiledMap.getHeight() - CAMERA_HEIGHT);

but I'm not sure that this is correct way..